# Interchangeable PHP version in XAMPP?

Tags: php, mariadb, xampp, moodle

So currently I am trying to install Moodle on my xampp but the latest version of xampp has MariaDB version 10.4 but the latest version of Moodle which supports PHP 8.2 requires MariaDB 10.6.7. I tried the possible ways of upgrading MariaDB in xampp but couldn't succeed so thought of working on an older version of Moodle but those version doesn't support the latest PHP version.

I am confused so is there a way to change the version of PHP in XAMPP? If you anyone could help on that.

Comment: Do you want to change the PHP version, or the MariaDB version?

Comment: Also, if XAMPP does not provide these versions, why not install each component seperately?

Comment: As Nico said previously, it'd be better to install each component you need separately, (apache, mariadb, moosh, ...). If you're on a windows environment one other solution could be to install ubuntu/debian in WSL which'll require a bit of training at first but will be a lot more modular and easier to keep you configuration to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can only change the PHP/Mysql version by installing the right XAMPP version (see https://www.apachefriends.org/). I personally recommend you to take a look to [DDEV](https://ddev.com/) for your local enviroment.